# Error BC30663 Attribute 'CompilerGeneratedAttribute' & 'DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, resources

after converting from C# to VB.NET an error appears. `Error BC30663 Attribute 'CompilerGeneratedAttribute' & 'DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times`
But when run in C# there is no error problem,

Please Guide Me

Thanks

Code In Vb.net

```vb
Namespace My.Resources

    <GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "16.0.0.0")>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode>
    <CompilerGenerated, _
    Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
    Global.System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute(), _
    Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.HideModuleNameAttribute()>
    Friend Module Resources

        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>
        Friend ReadOnly Property ResourceManager() As ResourceManager
            Get
                If Resources.resourceMan Is Nothing Then
                    Resources.resourceMan = New ResourceManager("Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                End If
                Return Resources.resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property

        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>
        Friend Property Culture() As CultureInfo
            Get
                Return Resources.resourceCulture
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As CultureInfo)
                Resources.resourceCulture = value
            End Set
        End Property


        Private resourceMan As ResourceManager

        Private resourceCulture As CultureInfo
    End Module
End Namespace
```

Below Code in C#

```cs
namespace Utils.Properties
{
    [GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "16.0.0.0")]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    internal class Resources
    {
        
        internal Resources()
        {
        }

    
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static ResourceManager ResourceManager
        {
            get
            {
                if (Resources.resourceMan == null)
                {
                    Resources.resourceMan = new ResourceManager("Utils.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                }
                return Resources.resourceMan;
            }
        }

        
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
        internal static CultureInfo Culture
        {
            get
            {
                return Resources.resourceCulture;
            }
            set
            {
                Resources.resourceCulture = value;
            }
        }

    
        private static ResourceManager resourceMan;

        
        private static CultureInfo resourceCulture;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try to address this yourself?  It's a trivial issue: the attributes appear twice on the VB code and once on the C# code, so it's unsurprising that the VB code is giving an error.  It's slightly hidden by the full namespace qualification on the second attribute declaration in VB, but you should still be able to clearly see that there are 6 attributes in VB vs only 3 in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Craig suggestion, finally the problem is solved

```
Namespace Utils.Properties

    <GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "16.0.0.0")>
    <DebuggerNonUserCode>
    <CompilerGenerated>
    Friend Class Resources
        
        Friend Sub New()
        End Sub

    
        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>
        Friend Shared ReadOnly Property ResourceManager As ResourceManager
            Get
                If Resources.resourceMan Is Nothing Then
                    Resources.resourceMan = New ResourceManager("My.Resources", GetType(Resources).Assembly)
                End If
                Return Resources.resourceMan
            End Get
        End Property

        
        <EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)>
        Friend Shared Property Culture As CultureInfo
            Get
                Return Resources.resourceCulture
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As CultureInfo)
                Resources.resourceCulture = value
            End Set
        End Property

        
        Private Shared resourceMan As ResourceManager

        Private Shared resourceCulture As CultureInfo
    End Class
End Namespace
```